# URLlauncher does n't support for deeplinking in iOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-deep-link

When I click on a link in the same app where it need to be redirected to another page, instead of redirecting to that page it is opening a in-app web browser in iOS Flutter. For android it is working good.

This happens in a chat app where customer send a link of some other conversation, where it does n't need to navigate to other browser.

I have hosted the site association file and tested the deep-linking as well and it is working fine.

I have tried adding the below code in `info.plist` file but does n't work

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
     <array>
          <string>https://app.example.com</string>
     </array>
```

Comment: Hey, Can you share your url schema that you need to open.

Comment: https://app.example.com/coversation/:conversationId